# "would they ... or they would ...?" or "would they ... or would they ...?"

Tags: grammar, questions

I don't know how to ask a conditional question using "or" between two questions:

"If they deliver the load to recovery facilities as a mixed load, would they be charged according to the mixed load fees or would they be charged less if the facility sort their load?"

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask

```
would they X or Y?
```

the question asks whether either of the consequences will occur, but it doesn't imply that they are mutually exclusive -- both *X* and *Y* could occur.

But if you ask

```
would they X or would they Y?
```

it implies that a choice is being made between *X* and *Y*.

Answer (score 0):

The word order of a question is all the time: aux. - pron. - verb - rest. That's why methinks that your sentence is correct. (it's ok to ask)